# htaccess move to mamp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm setting up a working copy of a site, and copied the entire site to a mamp. But I have problem setting up a working version of .htaccess.

Working directory on localhost is "folder1".

This is the live .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite site site.eu to site.eu/en/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !language=(sv|en|ru|jp)
RewriteRule ^$ en/ [L,R=301]
# Add trailing slash if necessary
RewriteRule ^(sv|en|ru|jp)$  $1/ [R=301,L]

# Add language part to old bookmarks/links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(sv|en|ru|jp)/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !language=(sv|en|ru|jp)
RewriteRule (sale|brands|latest_in_stock)(.*) en/$1$2 [R=301,L]

# Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.eu/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(sv|en|ru|jp)/(.*)$  $2?language=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^sale sale.php [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^brands/([^/]+) /designer.php?idnr=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^brands /labelList.php [L,QSA,NC]
...
```

On the local copy I changed to:

```
RewriteBase /folder1/
```

I tried to removed the part with "Add language code to old... " and the part "Remove www".
I also tried different changes to the last RewriteRule for exampel adding "folder1" and remove it from RewriteBase.

```
RewriteRule ^brands /folder1/labelList.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

The php-files and the index-file is working fine, but none of the /brands for example. I get a 500 error, too many redirects.

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `%{REQUEST_URI}` will contain the part behind the domain name, regardless of which .htaccess file it is in. What will happen is the following:

We start with `localhost/en/brands/asdf`. It matches the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(sv|en|ru|jp)/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !language=(sv|en|ru|jp)
RewriteRule (sale|brands|latest_in_stock)(.*) en/$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

The first condition is true, because `^/(sv|en|ru|jp)/` does not match `/folder1/en/...`. The second condition is true, because we haven't reached the rule yet that sets the language in the query string. Finally it will match the last one, because `(sale|brands|latest_in_stock)(.*)` will match `en/brands/asdf` (`$1` will contain `brands` and `$2` will contain `/asdf`). This will redirect to `localhost/folder1/en/brands/asdf` after re-adding the directory-prefix.

You have several options:

**1. adding folder1 to the condition**

If you add folder1 to the condition with `%{REQUEST_URI}`, this problem does not occur:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/(sv|en|ru|jp)/
```

**2. adding a negative look-ahead**

If you add a negative look-ahead to the rule, and remove the condition, things work out correctly, because the first argument of `RewriteRule` will match against what you expect. The pro of this is that you do not need to know in which directory this is:

```
#Remove this: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(sv|en|ru|jp)/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !language=(sv|en|ru|jp)
RewriteRule ^(?!(sv|en|ru|jp)/)[^/]*/?(sale|brands|latest_in_stock)(.*) en/$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

You might need to alter the capture group references. I can't test them here.

**3. Moving rules around**

Moving the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(sv|en|ru|jp)/(.*)$  $2?language=$1 [L,QSA]
```

just above the rule I just pointed out should theoretically solve this problem. I would strongly recommend **against** this solution, because intermixing redirects and rewrites makes it very hard to read.